# RTC ignore specific lines in source

Tags: version-control, rtc, jazz

I have a project that generates JavaScript files. I'll like to add date and time for when these files where generated. But i want RTC to ignore these lines.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

> But i want RTC to ignore these lines.

This is not possible with Jazz RTC.

And you don't add versioning metadata (like who modifies what) in a data (the file).

What you want to see is done with **[RTC annotate](https://jazz.net/library/article/574)**.

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/3.0/file-annotation-usage/images/annotation.png]

But if you *generate* a file with those information, then you could add that generated file to a `.jazzignore`, in order to make sure RTC doesn't try to check it in.

You can use [`lscm annotate`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/rational-team-concert-command-line-reference/) in order to generate such a file.
See this example:

```
$ lscm annotate flux.capacitor/requirements.txt 
1 Marty (8556) 2009-11-04 02:47 PM                    - Must not need any more than 1.5 gigawatts of power 
2 Marty (8556) 2009-11-04 02:47 PM                    - Determine minimum necessary speed 
3 Doc   (8616) 2009-11-04 02:47 PM Results of initial t - Initial trials suggest 60kmh
```

You can redirect the output of that command to a file:

```
$ lscm annotate flux.capacitor/requirements.txt > flux.capacitor/requirements.annotated
```

Comment: The code that i'm generating is to be delivered to a customer who is not using RTC and therefore can't use RTC annotations.

Comment: Then you can add the file you are generating to .jazzignore, in order for Jazz RTC to ignore it completely.

Comment: @KlausChristiansen I have edited the answer accordingly.